# Programmatically create and position an NSButton in a macOS app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsbutton

How do I programmatically create and position a button in a macOS Cocoa application?

Answer (score 19):

To possition button You need to change the button's origins x and y. Look at the sample code which I wrote below and comments.

**You can do it like this:**

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {

    //Start from bottom left corner

    int x = 100; //possition x
    int y = 100; //possition y

    int width = 130;
    int height = 40; 

    NSButton *myButton = [[[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(x, y, width, height)] autorelease];
    [[windowOutlet contentView] addSubview: myButton];
    [myButton setTitle: @"Button title!"];
    [myButton setButtonType:NSMomentaryLightButton]; //Set what type button You want
    [myButton setBezelStyle:NSRoundedBezelStyle]; //Set what style You want

    [myButton setTarget:self];
    [myButton setAction:@selector(buttonPressed)];
}

-(void)buttonPressed {
    NSLog(@"Button pressed!"); 

    //Do what You want here...  
}
```

** *WindowOutlet* is window so don't forget to IBOutlet it.

Answer (score 0):

All buttons are controls and all controls are views, so see, in order:

- The [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/)
- The [Control and Cell Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ControlCell/)
- The [Button Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Button/)

Comment: You should never link someone to apple documentation as an answer. It's never the answer. No one learns or understands anything in this format.