# Adding NSMatrix of buttons (NSRadioModeMatrix) in custom view, setting target/action

Tags: objective-c, macos, custom-view, nstabview

I am subclassing NSTabView to customise the appearance. I want to use an NSMatrix of NSButtonCells to select the tabs. I managed to add the NSMatrix with buttons in the initWithFrame: method of my NSTabView subclass. What I can not get to work is setting the target and action programmatically. Here is what I tried:

## define TAB_WIDTH 24.0f

## define TAB_HEIGHT 24.0f

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];

    if (self) {

        NSInteger numberOfTabs = 5;
        NSInteger tabSpacing = 8;

        NSSize cellSize = NSMakeSize(TAB_WIDTH, TAB_HEIGHT);
        NSSize interCellSpacing = NSMakeSize(tabSpacing, 0);

        CGFloat tabSelectorWidth = TAB_WIDTH * numberOfTabs + tabSpacing * numberOfTabs - 1;
        CGFloat xOrigin = (frameRect.size.width - tabSelectorWidth) / 2;

        NSRect tabSelectorFrame = NSMakeRect(xOrigin, 0, tabSelectorWidth, TAB_HEIGHT);

        NSButtonCell *cellPrototype = [[NSButtonCell alloc] init];

        [cellPrototype setBordered:NO];

        _tabSelector = [[NSMatrix alloc] initWithFrame:tabSelectorFrame
                                                  mode:NSRadioModeMatrix
                                             prototype:cellPrototype
                                          numberOfRows:1
                                       numberOfColumns:5];

        [_tabSelector setTarget:self];
        [_tabSelector setAction:@selector(selectedTab)];

        [_tabSelector setCellSize:cellSize];
        [_tabSelector setIntercellSpacing:interCellSpacing];

        NSArray *theCells = [_tabSelector cells];

        [theCells[0] setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"tab1"]];
        [theCells[1] setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"tab2"]];
        [theCells[2] setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"tab3"]];
        [theCells[3] setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"tab4"]];
        [theCells[4] setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"tab5"]];

        [self addSubview:_tabSelector];

        [self setDrawsBackground:NO];
        [self setTabViewType:NSNoTabsNoBorder];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)selectTab:(NSMatrix *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"selected tab");
}
```

The view is drawn as desired, but clicking the buttons does not call the target method.

I have tried to add buttons programmatically to a standard IB view as described here [Programatically create and position an NSButton in an OS X app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251703/programatically-create-and-position-an-nsbutton-in-an-os-x-app)

That works, but things fall apart in my custom view. Can anybody give me a hint what I am missing?

Martin

Comment: Speculation: Try using `id` rather than `NSMatrix*` as the type of `sender` for `selectTab` -- I'm not sure the "sender" here will be the matrix vs. the embedded buttons.  It may be the paradigm is to determine what got clicked by figuring out which button is the sender.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
 `   [_tabSelector setAction:@selector(selectedTab)];`
```

To

```
 `   [_tabSelector setAction:@selector(selectedTab:)];`
```

Comment: @Martin If you are still around, you should accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: No big deal. He benefitted. Others may benefit too. Solution is a typo or easy to miss colon for first time users of the idiom.